# REST API not Posting Content in Draft Mode

Tags: rest-api

HTML markup →

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Quick Add Post Shortcode
Description: Adds a shortcode for displaying a quick add post form.
*/

// Enqueue the CSS file
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_plugin_enqueue_styles' );
function your_plugin_enqueue_styles() {
  $css_folder = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/';
  wp_enqueue_style( 'plugin-style', $css_folder . 'style.css' );
  $js_folder = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/';
  wp_enqueue_script( 'plugin-script', $js_folder . 'main.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
  wp_localize_script( 'plugin-script', 'additionalData', array(
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ),
    'siteURL' => site_url(),
  ) );
}


// Register the shortcode
add_shortcode( 'quick_add_post', 'quick_add_post_shortcode' );

// Shortcode callback function
function quick_add_post_shortcode() {
    ob_start(); // Start output buffering
    
    // HTML markup
    ?>
    <div class="admin-quick-add">
        <h3>Quick Add Post</h3>
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title">
        <textarea name="content" placeholder="Content"></textarea>
        <button id="quick-add-button">Create Post</button>
        <div id="response"></div>
    </div>
    <?php
    
    return ob_get_clean(); // Return and clear output buffer
}
```

JS:

```
// Quick Add Post AJAX
var quickAddBtn = document.querySelector('#quick-add-button');

if( quickAddBtn ) {
  quickAddBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var ourPostData = {
      "title" : document.querySelector('.admin-quick-add [name="title"]').value,
      "content" : document.querySelector('.admin-quick-add [name="content"]').value,
      "status": "publish"
    }

    var createPost = new XMLHttpRequest();

    createPost.open('POST', additionalData.siteURL + "/wp-json/wp/v2/posts");
    createPost.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', additionalData.nonce);
    createPost.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    createPost.send(JSON.stringify(ourPostData));
    createPost.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(createPost.readyState == 4) {
        if( createPost.status == 201 ) {
            document.querySelector('.admin-quick-add [name="title"]').value = '';
            document.querySelector('.admin-quick-add [name="content"]').value = '';
        } else {
            alert('Error - Try again.');
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

REST API not Posting Content in Draft Mode. This is directly creating final post, but I want in draft mode. where should I handle setting during from submissions? or in Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Believe you need to be setting the `status` to `draft`, not `publish`

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/